# Role based login authentication in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have made two forms to register employers and helpers. Now i want to do login authentication with only one form. How can i do this such that when user clicks on login the values match with both employers and helpers table and whereever the values match it just login? This is for one.

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
var username = request.body.username;
var password = request.body.pwd;
if (username && password) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM fyp_helpers WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            request.session.loggedin = true;
            request.session.username = username;
            response.redirect('/home');
        } else {
            response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
        }           
        response.end();
    });
} else {
    response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    response.end();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at the SQL layer, this is an easy way of doing this. I'm assuming there is an fyp_employers table.

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.pwd;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM fyp_helpers WHERE username = ? AND password = ? UNION SELECT * FROM fyp_employeers WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password, username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("An error occurred:", error);
                response.send('Oops, something went wrong!');
            } else if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                 response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes i was looking for something like this but it is showing error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Oh yes, we need to check for an error, I'll update the code. I suspect a query error is occurring...

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 private functions one for checking its an employe and one for checking if its an helper.

This would make it easyer in the future to make changes like 2 seperate login forms or diffrent functionalities behind it.

I also would make a role based model but for this i suggest you folow a [guide](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/28/nodejs-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api).

```html
function helperAuthentication(username, password){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM fyp_helpers WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
          if (results.length > 0) {
              request.session.loggedin = true;
              request.session.username = username;
              response.redirect('/home');
          } else {
              return false
          }           
}

function employeeAuthentication(username, password){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM fyp_employees WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
          if (results.length > 0) {
              request.session.loggedin = true;
              request.session.username = username;
              response.redirect('/home');
          } else {
              return false
          }           
}

app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
var username = request.body.username;
var password = request.body.pwd;
if (username && password) {
    if(!helperAuthentication(username,password) && !employeeAuthentication(usernamen,password){
      response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
      response.end();
    }
    });
} else {
    response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    response.end();
}
});
```